# Vagrant and / or Docker workflow with full OS X filesystem integration for seamless local feel?

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, development-environment, docker, boot2docker

Recently I've been dabbling with `vagrant` and `docker`.  These are quite interesting tools, but I haven't been able to convince myself that it's the way to go quite yet on my OS X machine.  Being an old Unix hat, I have to say that I like having a consolidated and sandboxed environment for development purposes.

I've seen a lot of chatter and a number of friends have been using `vagrant` with just stock `vim` for editing.  I'm not really a fan of that approach and would probably prefer to use the vm provider's sharing mechanism OR, more likely, NFS.

Personally I'd like to be able to edit directly in TextMate, SublimeText, Emacs (on OS X), or even perhaps use RubyMine and its various IDE features, etc.

Is there any way to really get the workflow down so that such an environment will be essentially like working on a local environment without having to pull a lot of additional background strings to make things work out?

I suppose a few well placed scripts could go a long way, but I've not found any solid answers on really making this a seamless environment.

Comment: Docker isn't _really_ meant for that use case, although it can be adapted to fit into a dev environment. I'd suggest looking into a Git/CI based workflow instead as sandboxing using docker locally tends to raise a lot of small annoyances. If you do want sandboxing, use vagrant. If you want highly portable microservices, use docker. Happy to expand on these or you can check out #docker on irc for more info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What actually worked for me was to use [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) which makes it easy to install a lightweight virtual machine (with VirtualBox) that will host your docker deamon and images. The only thing you need in order to run docker commands is to run $(boot2docker shellinit) when you open a new Terminal.

If you need to also have your files on an OS X folder and share them with a running docker image, you need some additional setup, but once you do it, you won't have to do it again.
Have a look [here](https://medium.com/boot2docker-lightweight-linux-for-docker/boot2docker-together-with-virtualbox-guest-additions-da1e3ab2465c) for a nice walkthrough on how to do it. The steps in short are:

- Get a special boot2docker image that allows you to use shared folders for VirtualBox
- Configure VirtualBox to share a folder:

  `VBoxManage sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm -name home -hostpath /Users`

  This will share your /Users folder with the boot2docker image that hosts docker.
- From you Mac share the folder you need with a folder in a docker image like:

  `docker run -it -v /Users/me/dev/my-project:/root/src:rw ubuntu /bin/bash`

One small annoyance that I haven't found how to overcome is that you do not longer access your software through localhost because it actually runs on boot2docker instance. You have to run `boot2docker ip` and access that ip.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Re localhost access: if you want to access docker container's public ports from your host machine's localhost you need to get Virtual Machine to forward the boot2docker ports for you.  The details of doing this can be found in [boot2docker/doc/WORKAROUNDS](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md).